# What is wrong in my c++ merge sorting code plz help me

Tags: c++, sorting

Help me where I am wrong. Why I don't get a sorted array as my output.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void mergalgo(int arr[], int start, int mid , int end){
    int resultant[5] {};
    int l=0;
    int k= mid+1;

    while(start<mid && k <end){
        if (arr[start]> arr[k]){
            resultant[l++] = arr[k++];
        }
        else{
            resultant[l++]= arr[start++];
        }
    }

    while(start<mid){
        resultant[l++]= arr[k++];
    }

    while(k<end){
        resultant[l++]= arr[k++];
    }

    for(int s=0; s<=end ;s++){
        arr[s]= resultant[s];
    }
}

void mergesort(int arr[], int start , int end){
    //base condition
    if(start<=end){
        return;
    }
    else{
        int mid= (start + end)/2;
        mergesort(arr, start, mid);
        mergesort(arr,mid+1,end);
        
        // merge algo
        mergalgo(arr, start, mid, end);
    }
}

int main(){
    int arr[5] {12,4,5,2,7};
    int start=0;
    int end=4;
    mergesort(arr,start,end);

    //sortd array
    for(int i= 0; i<=4; i++){
        cout<< arr[i]<< " "<< endl;
    }
}
```

Help me where i am wrong. I am new in C++ so plz do not try to use vectors plz use normal pointer so that i can understand it better.

And also help me on my test cases.. is it right or not because as i already told that .. I am new in programming so do not know that much clearly about all test cases..

Comment: Even if you don't want to use a debugger, you can make modifications to your program to test assumptions. Outputting values of variables is a good start. Your task is to ensure your implementation of the algorithm works the way you expect it to. Probing the program's behavior to find places where it's _not_ doing what you expect is called "debugging", and is an essential skill to practice.

Comment: Vectors are easier to parse than raw pointers. That's an odd request.

Comment: a debugger knows how many items in a vector but not in a pointer so you have to specify it manually. Learn how to debug. It's a required skill going forward [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/995714)

Comment: `if(start<=end){ return; }` Take a good look at that. This may help: https://godbolt.org/z/6d1vn38vx Once you figure that out you'll want to look at `while(start<mid)` and figure out when that will end since `start` and `mid` do not change inside the loop. I'll let you debug it from there.

Comment: Who is teaching you C++? The code looks like code written before 1998... the year that std::vector was introduced to replace "C" style arrays. If you can use C++20 consider [std::span](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span).

Comment: "I am new in C++ so plz do not try to use vectors plz use normal pointer so that i can understand it better." That is inconsistent, if you are new to C++ you should learn how to use vectors instead of C-like constructs. " I am new in programming so do not know that much clearly about all test cases." also is not clear to me. In fact I think what you mean by "I am new" is "My teacher wants ...". Which is fine (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions ) but you should be more open about it.

Comment: Good read: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I am new to "C++" this is an excellent reason to use std::vector. It is NOT advanced C++, it is basic C++. It will safe you from a lot of the headaches with "C" style arrays, specialy if you use the `.at(index)` method instead of the `[index]` operator.

Comment: Learn C++ from : [a recent C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or from [learncpp.com](https://www.learncpp.com/) that site is decent and pretty up to date.
Then use [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) for reference material (and examples). When you have done all that keep using [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) to keep up to date with the latest best practices since C++ keeps evolving.

Comment: "I am new in C++ so plz do not try to use vectors..." thats a misunderstanding. Being new to c++ is not reason to not use `std::vector` but a reason to not use c-arrays. `std::vector` is the simple way. c-arrays are not for beginners.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not return a sorted array because of a logical mistake. The condition of the base case in the mergesort function is where the problem is.

You currently possess:

```
if (start <= end) {
    return;
}
```

To correctly identify the base case, this condition needs to be reversed to

```
if (start >= end)
```

Your code should now output the sorted array after this correction.

Comment: Looks like the mod strike is starting to show.